# MySQL get crash daily at particular time

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, innodb

I am running mysql container. It crashes daily at particuler time and restart automatically. I have checked the logs as below:
Why It is crashed and restarted at that time.?

```
Version: '5.7.31'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.pSLGjjQT7y/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221007Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221028Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221034Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221042Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221101Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221712Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221728Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221736Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221744Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221753Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221760Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221800Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221810Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221823Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221832Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221839Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221846Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221854Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221861Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221869Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221876Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221883Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221891Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221898Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221905Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221913Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221920Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221928Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221935Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221943Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221950Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221957Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221965Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221972Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221980Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221987Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.221994Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222002Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222009Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222016Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222024Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222031Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222038Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222046Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222112Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-08-04T23:20:33.222236Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-08-04T23:20:33.322517Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-08-04T23:20:33.322828Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200804 23:20:33
2020-08-04T23:20:35.756199Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2720090
2020-08-04T23:20:35.758006Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-08-04T23:20:35.758024Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-08-04T23:20:35.758031Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-08-04T23:20:35.758039Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-08-04T23:20:35.758044Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-08-04T23:20:35.758213Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-08-04T23:20:35.759186Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

This happens daily at given time and affects other applications as well.

Comment: That doesn't look like a crash, that's a graceful shutdown. Something is shutting it down deliberately. Like a server reboot? Or someone has executed the [SHUTDOWN;](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/shutdown.html) satement?

Comment: Who is doing the hosting?  Could it be a DAILY Maintenance process?  What time of day?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Im running mysql in GKE cluster. That's not maintenance. around 3:00 pm UTC.

Comment: Could you get a General Log recorded starting two minutes before the expected shutdown for analysis?

Comment: It's not crashed yesterday, don't know why.